# SailsJS 1.0 + SQL Server adapter compatibility?

Tags: sails.js

I am trying to connect sails 1.0 to SQL Server, but I've been out of luck so far. There doesn't seem to be anything publicly available.

I did found someone [on GitHub](https://github.com/lentiummmx/sails-mssqlserver/commit/f9ac32bbd75194b7eb453ae863ec35e98ba150e9) that did try to add support, although when i try to use their branch it didn't work out too well.

Got this error when I try to use the `model.findOne()` method.

> name: 'RequestError',
>   message: 'Incorrect syntax near \'BY\'.',
>   code: 'EREQUEST',
>   number: 102,
>   lineNumber: 1,
>   state: 1,
>   class: 15,
>   serverName: 'sql1b',
>   procName: '',
>   precedingErrors: [] }

Was anyone else more lucky in getting sails 1.0 to work with a SQL Server database?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can try [sails-sqlserver-sailsv1](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-sqlserver-sailsv1). But don't follow the guide in the npm site, probably a copy/paste error on how to install the package. use:

`npm install sails-sqlserver-sailsv1 --save`

And in the **datastore** configuration on sails make sure to use the correct adapter name:

`default: {
    adapter: 'sails-sqlserver-sailsv1',
    user: 'cnect',
    password: 'pass',
    host: 'abc123.database.windows.net' // azure database
    database: 'mydb',
    options: {
      encrypt: true   // use this for Azure databases
    }
  }`

I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to change from waterline - default SailS ORM - to  [Sequelize](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/) + [Tedious](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tedious). Waterline is very dependent on the work of the opensource community, and thus SQL Server is not (and I don't think it will ever be) supported.

Comment: Interesting, will play around with both libraries